# Processing a data_frame: Defining when the value of a column change one unit

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following data structure:

```
iid<-c(rep("I1",5),rep("I2",5),rep("I3",5),rep("I4",5))
days<-rep(c(0,2,5,7,14),4)
estatus<-c(4,4,4,3,3,
           5,4,4,4,3,
           4,4,4,4,4,
           5,4,4,3,2)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(iid,days,estatus))
```

I'm interested in obtained different outcomes all related to changes in the variable "status"
First I want to know how many individuals (iid) have changed their status in 1 unit by the day 5. I don't want to treat days as a factor, this is a simple example, but in the real dataset days can change between individuals, so I don't have always the same days.

The first outcome would look like this:

```
iid<-c("I1","I2","I3","I4")
res_5<-c(0,1,0,1)
results_1<-as.data.frame(cbind(iid,res_5))
```

I1 and I3 did not experience a change in their status of 1 unit.

The second outcome I'm interested in is to know on which day the status of each individual changes 1 unit in their status. The outcome would be like:

```
iid<-c("I1","I2","I3","I4")
res_d<-c(7,2,NA,2)
results_1<-as.data.frame(cbind(iid,res_d))
```

I think that I got the first part of the problem, as I know how to aggregate by iid with tidyverse or dplyr. However, I don't know how to check if a certain row is 1, 2 or n units above or below the previous row.

Comment: You can use `by` to apply a function fo the different iid of your data.frame: `by(data, data$iid, your_function)`. Look at `diff` function, it gives you the difference between consecutive elements of your vector: `diff(c(5, 4, 4, 3, 2))` will give you `[1] -1  0 -1 -1`

Comment: Awesome. I'm having a problem: `diff(data$estatus` works perfectly. But, `by(data,data$iid,diff(data$estatus))`  threw this error: Error in FUN(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) : can't find function "FUN"

Comment: `your_function <- function(x) {return(diff(x$estatus))}` and `by(data, data$iid, your_function)`. In `your_function`, you can perform more complex treatment such as looking for the index where diff is equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

Using `by` to apply a function for each id.

(i) look for the index where days == 5 and check the diff with the first element

(ii) use `diff` to compute the difference of consecutive elements in your vector and then look for a difference of 1 or -1

```r
iid <- c(rep("I1", 5), rep("I2", 5), rep("I3", 5), rep("I4", 5))
days <- rep(c(0, 2, 5, 7, 14), 4)
estatus <- c(
  4, 4, 4, 3, 3,
  5, 4, 4, 4, 3,
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
  5, 4, 4, 3, 2
)
data <- data.frame(iid = iid, days = days, estatus = estatus)

my_func1 <- function(x) {
  ind5 <- which(x$days == 5) 
  d <- x$estatus[ind5] - x$estatus[1]
  
  return((d == 1) | (d == -1))
}

by(data, data$iid, my_func1)


my_func2 <- function(x) {
  d <- diff(x$estatus)
  hasChangeOf1 <- (d == 1) | (d == -1)
  
  return(x$days[which(hasChangeOf1)[1] + 1])
}


by(data, data$iid, my_func2)
```